# How can I grant a specific role In Ubercart?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, e-commerce, ubercart

I'm trying to grant a specific role to users that order an amount equal or greater than 100.00 €: Conditional Actions is going really near the achievement, but I'm failing on the action (PHP required).

How can I grant a role using a PHP action in Ubercart Conditional Actions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign role with PHP in Drupal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533415/how-to-assign-role-with-php-in-drupal)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I can't remember why I submitted the same question twice on the same day...the other one has received more attention though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a couple of [related](http://www.ubercart.org/comment/54046) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533415/how-to-assign-role-with-php-in-drupal), I think you want to add an "Execute custom PHP code" action along the lines of the following (substituting in the appropriate role name in line #3):

```
if($account) {
  $uid = $account->uid;
  $role_name = 'YOUR SPECIFIC ROLE NAME GOES HERE';
  $rid = db_result(db_query("SELECT rid FROM {role} WHERE name = '%s'", $role_name));

  // Load user object
  $account = user_load(array('uid' => 1));

  // Save the user object with the new roles.
  if ($account !== FALSE) {
    $roles = $account->roles + array($rid => $role_name);
    user_save($account, array('roles' => $roles));

  watchdog('user', 'uc ca added role to Ubercart created user');
```

Comment: I would rather suggest the usage of the core `user_multiple_role_edit()` function: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_multiple_role_edit/6, where the `$accounts` has to be an array of uids, the `$operation` has to be equal to `"add_role"`, and the `$rid` has to be equal to the id of the given role (which you can discover with a search of the return value of `user_roles()`: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/6). It's very easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

Code provided needs to close two brackets. I dropped the `if` statements, grabbed the uid from the order and fixed the uid setting (it was '1'):

```
  $uid = $order->uid;
  $role_name = 'customer';
  $rid = db_result(db_query("SELECT rid FROM {role} WHERE name = '%s'", $role_name));

  // Load user object
  $account = user_load(array('uid' => $uid));

  // Save the user object with the new roles.
  $roles = $account->roles + array($rid => $role_name);
  user_save($account, array('roles' => $roles));

  watchdog('user', 'uc ca added role to Ubercart created user');
```